# Opening .m files DIRECTLY in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 and have MATLAB installed on my computer. I wanted to know if there was any way to open .m file directly in MATLAB without having to go through the painful process of starting MATLAB, and navigating through folders to open up desired scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Try [changing file associations](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=212586) for .m files so that you can double click on them and have them open in the MATLAB editor.

Comment: So what do you do if you right click on the .m file open with and Matlab isn't an option. Similarly, if you right click on the file and go to properties and then try to select matlab, again its not in the list. (Some people said custom command and I saw this however this was in an older version of ubuntu. (Im using 16.04)

Answer (score 1):

A [startup](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/startup.html) file for user-defined options may fit your needs. Or have a look at [shortcuts](http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2007/03/29/shortcuts-for-commonly-used-code/) by Mike.

Answer (score 1):

To open an m-file from matlab w/o navigating through menus:

```
>>edit myfile
```

The extension .m is assumed. This requires that myfile.m is in matlab's search path.

To add your favorite locations to matlab's search path, try

```
>>pathtool
```

and choose SAVE so the locations are preserved for your next Matlab session.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is appending `%F` to the end of `Exec=some/path` which is in my `matlab.desktop` file.

Locate the `matlab.desktop` file its either in `~/.local/share/applications` or `~/usr/share/applications`.

[Solution from here](https://askubuntu.com/a/483334/662944)

---

Also if you don't have a matlab.desktop file then you may want to create one [link to some relevant help to create launcher icon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/401948/how-to-create-launcher-icon/562866#562866)